# extracting texts based on font family type from html

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

i have a html data where i just want to extract texts which comes under bold font type.

```
<span style="font-family: ABCDEE+Cambria,Bold; font-size:9px">Pinecone Functions 
<br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:419px; top:1903px; width:76px; height:11px;"><span style="font-family: ABCDEE+Calibri,Bold; font-size:7px">Trainee Sign-Off 
<br></span></div>
```

I just want texts which are under font-family: ABCDEE+Cambria, Bold.

```
with open('/home/output4.html') as file:
    text = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

x = soup.find_all('span', style=re.compile(r'font-family: ABCDEE+Cambria,Bold.*'))
for rows in x:
    print(rows.text)
```

I have tried this bt getting empty lists as a result.

Comment: maybe also show the example of the html you are trying to parse / extract

Answer (score 0):

`+` is a special char in regex, you should escape it (notice the `\+` instead of `+`)

example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

text = """
<span style="font-family: ABCDEE+Cambria,Bold; font-size:9px">Pinecone Functions 
<br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:419px; top:1903px; width:76px; height:11px;"><span style="font-family: ABCDEE+Calibri,Bold; font-size:7px">Trainee Sign-Off 
<br></span></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

x = soup.find_all('span', style=re.compile(r'font-family: ABCDEE\+Cambria,Bold.*'))
for rows in x:
    print(rows.text)
```

Output:

> Pinecone Functions

Comment: it is also giving other other font type text which do not have bold in it.

Comment: really? could you give an example? seems weird, as it must match the `Bold` in the regex pattern.

Comment: <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size:6px">cone is the Ar application that extracts, transforms, validates and loads client trade files into the 
<br>Platform.    
<br></span>

Comment: even texts from this html is getting printed

Comment: I don't know, I copied my code and changed the `text` to your new one, it returns nothing for me... even with original `text` and changing "Bold" to "Bod" returns nothing.